# How do I click-iterate over a list of web elements in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I'd like to be able to click on several links on a page of search results. To do this, I've tried to create a list of web elements finding all of the xpaths on a search results page that correspond with links. I would then like to be able to click on those links for each xpath and return to the search results page and click on the next link in the list.

So far I've been able to create a nested loop that scrapes all of the href tags on a page to create/find the xpath. The second level of the loop is intended to click on the link corresponding to that element in the list and then return to the search page to click on the next element in the list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")


WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'ventana02')))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'cellpadding' : '2'})
table_items = table.find_all('a')
for item in table_items:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href='" + item.get('href') + "']")
    print(elements)
    for elem in elements:
        elem.click()
        driver.back()
```

This coded will click on the first link on the search results page, go to that link and then click back to the search results page. But it does not iterate on to the next link in the element list. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the loop I wrote?

Comment: Yes. when you navigate back to search results, the elements will become stale and would no longer work. you will have to find those elements again.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ on tips about how to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you click on the element and page get refresh/loads then the selenium element references will be refreshed. So, you can not access them with the old references and when you try with old references you will get `StaleElementException`.

To work with the latest references of the element, you have to get the element(s) every time the page refreshed.

Here is your script with minimal changes to accommodate the request.

```
for iLink in range(iLinks):
    print(iLink)
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//table)[2]//td//a")[iLink]
    print (link.get_attribute('href'))
    # add link related logic here
    link.click()
    # you have to wait for the next element to display
    time.sleep(1)
    # click on back in browser
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.switch_to.frame('ventana02')
```

Comment: Can you please join [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197629/selenium-chat-room)

Comment: ahaa... Can you join a zoom session?